# How Chainlink VRF fulfillRandomWords() callback function works?

Tags: chainlink, randomness, vrf

I am using Chainlink VRF2 where I receive random numbers via a callback to this function:

```
function fulfillRandomWords(
    uint256, /* requestId */
    uint256[] memory randomWords
  ) internal override {
    s_randomWords = randomWords;
  }
```

This function supposedly will be called by VRF coordinator but the `fulfillRandomWords()` function has the access modifier `internal`. How does the VRFCoordinator send this function a random number if it is an external contract?

Answer (score 5):

In the import [VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/9ae2b4aafa22d60bde18337d502893f36748605a/contracts/src/v0.8/dev/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol) you will see the actual function being called by the VRFCoordinator is:

```js
function rawFulfillRandomWords(uint256 requestId, uint256[] memory randomWords) external {
    if (msg.sender != vrfCoordinator) {
      revert OnlyCoordinatorCanFulfill(msg.sender, vrfCoordinator);
    }
    fulfillRandomWords(requestId, randomWords);
  }
```

This external function calls `fulfillRandomWords()`, and because it is inherited, `fulfillRandomWords()` can be internal.

Reference: [VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol GitHub](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/9ae2b4aafa22d60bde18337d502893f36748605a/contracts/src/v0.8/dev/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol)